# Maven does not recognise src/main/java as the source folder for code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an issue in that in eclipse the folder "java" in src/main/java is considered as a package. The folder structure in which I have the code is "workspace\map_reduce\src\main\java\map_reduce". When i do "mvn clean install" it works fine, but when i integrate it with eclipse, the folder stricture is "src/main/" and the package is "java.map_reduce".

I want the folder structure as "src/main/java" and the package as "map_reduce".

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right click the project in [Project Explorer], from the popup context menu, select [Build Path] -> [Configure Build Path ...],  switch to tab [source], then remove "src/main/" and add folder "src/main/java" as source